# why en0 interface has two IPv4 ip?

Tags: node.js, ip

most of dev server will generate preview page use local ip like `http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx/index`.

Recently I find the page can't be rendered, after debugging, I found that the `en0` interface has two IPv4 ip, the useful one is the second, but most of library use the first, so I wonder how to choose the ip.

I wonder if it's normal has two ip in `en0`, and how to choose between both?

what effect the ip order, because OS version?